# Java Swing Resizing the JFrame and JPanel with all drawn Elements

Tags: java, swing, jframe, resize, layout-manager

I'm developing a game in Java Swing. I use absolut coords and a fixed window size in order to set every element in its place. But if I resize the JFrame, the drawn elements dont scale. How can I achieve that?
In my example I would set the default window size to 1280 x 720 and develop the game according to this size. Then it'd be perfect to just let java automatically resize the elements.

Comment: " I use absolut coords " - don't. Use [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: *" I use absolut coords and a fixed window size in order to set every element in its place. But if I resize the JFrame, the drawn elements don't scale"* - Well, yes, that's what layout managers do for you, but, if you want to reinvent the wheel, the you're going to have to do it manually yourself and devise you own ideas about the relationship between components and how they react to changes in the size of the container, how left over space is to be allocated and what to do when the available space is to small to fit the components

Comment: Or you could use the API which was designed to solve most of these issues for you. Pixel perfect layouts are an illusion, to many things break them; different font metrics; DPI; screen resolutions; video drivers; time to get over them. Instead focus on the user flow and interaction

Comment: Have a look at all the major GUI frameworks - most of them will have some kind of "layout management" framework - as the developers of those frameworks know, GUIs are complicated things and wasting time developing "scaling" algorithms means you're spending less time developing actual useful products.  Even layout management is complicated. You can use compound layouts to achieve advance results, but you need to take the time to understand what each manager does for you and why they are best suited for

Comment: If you're custom painting the elements, you have two choices. You either scale the `Graphics` context accordingly (using 1270x720 as a baseline), possibly using a `AffineTransform` or you allow you code to use the `width`/`height` of the container as the bounds for the game

Comment: @MadProgrammer *"If you're custom painting the elements.."* That's what it seems to me, in which case an appropriate (scaling) `AffineTransform` will almost make it a 'one line fix'.

Comment: *"I would set the default window size to 1280 x 720"* More often, the 'fixed size' applies not to the window, but to the content area (usually a panel inside the frame) that the game is painted in. Then the 'chrome' or decorations around the edges of the window make the entire GUI slightly larger, according to the PLAF being used, and the OS the code is running on. By focusing on making the content area to be the right size though, we can get the toolkit to take care of that extra space for us.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a fixed size window, you can use JFrame.setResizable(boolean) API to make your window non-resizable. Example:

```
public class FixedSizeJFrame
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("My Title");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1280, 720);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel("My Label"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JTextArea("Sample text"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: As a user, I just want to point out how much I hate non-resizable windows - your code also fails to take into account the possible differences in font metrics; DPI; screen resolutions that the code might need to be run on, further reducing the chance of user acceptance and usability

Comment: True. But I only wanted to demonstrate how setResizable() is used.